# Is there a python library for representing conditionals of two values as a matrix/table?

Tags: python

We're trying to figure out a way to easily pull values from what I guess I would describe as a grid of conditional statements.  We've got two variables, x and y, and depending on those values, we want to pull one of (something1, ..., another1, ... again1...).  We could definitely do this using if statements, but we were wondering if there was a better way.  Some caveats: we would like to be able to easily change the bounds on the x and y conditionals.  The problem with a bunch of if statements is that it's not very easy to compare the values of those bounds with the values in the example table below.

Example:

[image]
So if x = 4% and y = 30%, we would get back `another1`.  Whereas if x = 50% and y = 10%, we would get `something3`.

Overall two questions:

1. Is there a general name for this kind of problem?
2. Is there an easy framework or library that could do this for us without if statements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though Pandas is not really made for this kind of usage, with function aggregation and boolean indexing it allows for an elegant-ish solution for your problem. Alternatively, constraint-based programing might be an option (see [python-constraint on pypi](https://pypi.org/project/python-constraint/)).

1. Define the constraints as functions.

```py
x_constraints = [lambda x: 0 <= x < 5, 
                 lambda x: 5 <= x < 10, 
                 lambda x: 10<= x < 15,
                 lambda x: x >= 15
                ]
y_constraints = [lambda y: 0 <= y < 20, 
                 lambda y: 20 <= y < 50, 
                 lambda y: y >= 50]

x = 15
y = 30
```

2. Now we want to make two dataframes: One that only holds the x-values,
   and another that only holds the y-values where number of columns = number of x-constraints and number of rows = number of y-constraints.

```py
import pandas as pd

def make_dataframe(value):
    return pd.DataFrame(data=value, 
                        index=range(len(y_constraints)), 
                        columns=range(len(x_constraints)))

x_df = make_dataframe(x)
y_df = make_dataframe(y)
```

The dataframes look like this:

```
>>> x_df 
    0   1   2   3
0  15  15  15  15
1  15  15  15  15
2  15  15  15  15
>>> y_df
    0   1   2   3
0  30  30  30  30
1  30  30  30  30
2  30  30  30  30
```

3. Next, we need the dataframe `label_df` that holds the possible outcomes. The shape must match the dimension of `x_df` and `y_df` above. (What's cool about this is that you can store the data in a
   CSV-file and directly read it into a dataframe with `pd.read_csv` if you wish.)

```
label_df = pd.DataFrame([[f"{w}{i+1}" for i in range(len(x_constraints))] for w in "something another again".split()])
```

```
>>> label_df
            0           1           2           3
0  something1  something2  something3  something4
1    another1    another2    another3    another4
2      again1      again2      again3      again4
```

4. Next, we want to apply the `x_constraints` to the *columns* of `x_df`, and the `y_constraints` to the *rows* of `y_df`. `.aggregate` takes
   a dictionary that maps column or row names to functions `{colname: func}`,
   which we construct inline using `dict(zip(...))`. `axis=1` means "apply the functions row-wise".

```
x_mask = x_df.aggregate(dict(zip(x_df.columns, x_constraints)))
y_mask = y_df.aggregate(dict(zip(y_df.columns, y_constraints)), axis=1)
```

The result are two dataframes holding boolean values, and ideally,
there should be exactly one column in `x_mask` and one row in `y_mask` that's all `True`, e.g.

```
>>> x_mask
       0      1      2     3
0  False  False  False  True
1  False  False  False  True
2  False  False  False  True
>>> y_mask
       0      1      2      3
0  False  False  False  False
1   True   True   True   True
2  False  False  False  False
```

If we combine them with bit-wise and `&`, we get a boolean mask with exactly
one `True` value.

```py
>>> m = x_mask & y_mask
>>> m
       0      1      2      3
0  False  False  False  False
1  False  False  False   True
2  False  False  False  False
```

5. Use `m` to select the target value from `label_df`. The result `df` is all `NaN` except one value, which we extract with `df.stack().iloc[0]`:

```
>>> df = label_df[m]
     0    1    2         3
0  NaN  NaN  NaN       NaN
1  NaN  NaN  NaN  another4
2  NaN  NaN  NaN       NaN
>>> df.stack().iloc[0]
'another4'
```

And that's it! It should be very easy to maintain, by just changing the list of constraints and adapting the possible outcomes in `label_df`.

Comment: this is super helpful, thank you!!! I think the pandas stuff is a great backup, but that constraint package looks like what we're looking for

Comment: @Rory my pleasure. If you figure it out with the constraints, it would be nice if you post it as answer, too, for future reference :)

Answer (score 1):

I didn't hear about any name.
**If** (ha-ha) it should be more conceptually close to you, I might suggest that you create two mapper functions that would map x and y values to the categories of your contingency table.

```py
map_x = lambda x: 0 if x < 0.05 else 1 if x < 0.1 else 2
map_y = lambda y: 0 if y < 0.2 else 1 if y < 0.5 else 2
df.iloc[map_x(x), map_y(y)]
```

Comment: Thanks! This was also super helpful, but I think the python-constraint library that was posted on another comment is most like what we're looking for

Answer (score 1):

If you have just a handful of conditionals then you may define two lists with the upper bounds, and use a simple linear search:

```
x_bounds = [0.05, 0.1, 1.0]
y_bounds = [0.2, 0.5, 1.0]

def linear(x_bounds, y_bounds, x, y):
    for i,xb in enumerate(x_bounds):
        if x <= xb:
            break
    for j,yb in enumerate(y_bounds):
        if y <= yb:
            break
    return i,j

linear(x_bounds, y_bounds, 0.4, 3.0) #(0,1)
```

If there are many conditionals a binary search will be better:

```
def binary(x_bounds, y_bounds, x, y):
    lower = 0
    upper = len(x_bounds)-1
    while upper > lower+1:
        mid = (lower+upper)//2
        if x_bounds[mid] < x:
            lower = mid
        elif x_bounds[mid] >= x:
            if mid > 0 and x_bounds[mid-1] < x:
                xmid = mid
                break
            else:
                xmid = mid-1
                break
        else:
            upper = mid
    lower = 0
    upper = len(y_bounds)-1
    while upper > lower+1:
        mid = (lower+upper)//2
        if y_bounds[mid] < y:
            lower = mid
        elif y_bounds[mid] >= y:
            if mid > 0 and y_bounds[mid-1] < y:
                ymid = mid
                break
            else:
                ymid = mid-1
                break
        else:
            upper = mid
    return xmid,ymid

binary(x_bounds, y_bounds, 0.4, 3.0) #(0,1)
```